# Integral $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x\sin{x}}{1+\cos^4{x}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

**Question:**

Find the integral  $$I=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{x\sin{x}}{1+\cos^4{x}}dx$$

my try: since
$$I=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{x\sin{x}}{1+\cos^4{x}}dx$$

then I can't.

I know this follow integral
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac{x\cos{x}}{1+\sin^2{x}}dx=(arcsinh{1})^2-(\arcsin1)^2$$
(this nice integral  is sos440 solve it)
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac{x\sin{x}}{1+\cos^2{x}}dx=(\arcsin{1})^2-0^2$$
(this is very easy integral),because use $$\int_{0}^{\pi}xf(\sin{x})dx=\pi\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\sin{x})dx$$

But I can't my problem,Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have
$$I = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{x \sin(x)}{1+\cos^4(x)} dx = 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k\int_0^{\pi/2} x \sin(x) \cos^{4k}(x)dx$$
Now let $\cos(x) =t$. We then get
$$I_k = \int_0^{\pi/2} x \sin(x) \cos^{4k}(x)dx = \int_0^1 t^{4k} \arccos(t) dt$$
We now have
$$\int t^{4k} \arccos(t) dt = \dfrac{t^{4k+1}}{2(8k^2+6k+1)}(t _2F_1(1/2,2k+1;2k+2;t^2) + 2(2k+1) \arccos(t)) + c$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 t^{4k} \arccos(t) dt & = \dfrac1{2(8k^2+6k+1)}(_2F_1(1/2,2k+1;2k+2;1) + 2(2k+1) \arccos(1))\\
& = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{(4k+1)^2} \dfrac{\Gamma(2k+1)}{\Gamma(2k+1/2)}
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
I & = 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{(4k+1)^2} \dfrac{\Gamma(2k+1)}{\Gamma(2k+1/2)}\\
& = 2 _4F_3(1/4,1/2,1,1;3/4,5/4,5/4;-1)\\
& \approx 1.845096\ldots
\end{align}
where the last step is nothing but the definition of the appropriate [generalized hypergeometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_series), i.e.,
$$_4F_3(1/4,1/2,1,1;3/4,5/4,5/4;z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{(4k+1)^2} \dfrac{\Gamma(2k+1)}{\Gamma(2k+1/2)}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{%
I \equiv \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}{x\sin\pars{x} \over 1 + \cos^{4}\pars{x}}\,\dd x:\
{\large ?}}$

> $\large\tt\mbox{Hint:}$
> \begin{align}
> I &= 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\sin\pars{x}\,{1 \over 2\expo{\ic\pi/2}}\bracks{%
> {1 \over \cos^{2}\pars{x} - \expo{\ic\pi/2}} -
> {1 \over \cos^{2}\pars{x} + \expo{\ic\pi/2}}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=
> 2\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{x\sin\pars{x} \over \cos^{2}\pars{x} - \expo{\ic\pi/2}}\,\dd x
> =
> 2\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{x\sin\pars{x} \over 2\expo{\ic\pi/4}}\bracks{%
> {1 \over \cos\pars{x} - \expo{\ic\pi/4}} -
> {1 \over \cos\pars{x} + \expo{\ic\pi/4}}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=
> \Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\sin\pars{x}\,{\root{2} \over 2}\pars{1 - \ic}
> \braces{2\ic\,\Im\bracks{1 \over \cos\pars{x} - \expo{\ic\pi/4}}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=
> \root{2}\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{x\sin\pars{x} \over \cos\pars{x} - \expo{\ic\pi/4}}
> \,\dd x
> \end{align}

G&R-$7^{\ul{\rm a}}$ ed. has an identity $\pars{~{\bf 2.647}.2,\ \mbox{pag.}\ 224~}$ which seems close to this integral but unfortunately it's only valid for $\color{#0000ff}{\large m \not= 1}$:
$$
\int{x^{n}\sin\pars{x}\,\dd x \over \bracks{a + b\cos\pars{x}}^{m}}
=
{x^{n} \over \pars{m - 1}\bracks{a + b\cos\pars{x}}^{m - 1}}
-
{n \over \pars{m - 1}b}\int{x^{n - 1}\,\dd x \over \bracks{a + b\cos\pars{x}}^{m - 1}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I might be confused, but since $\int \frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^4 x} dx$ is quite easy to integrate (call the integral $F(x),$ it has an arctan and some logs), your integral is easily done by parts, where the answer is $x F(x)\left|_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\right. - \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} F(x) d x.$

Comment: You forgot the $x$ before $\sin(x)$.

Comment: @0912 No, I did not.

Comment: And how do you integrate $F(x)$?

Comment: @Sanchez $F(x)$ is a sum of arctans and logs of linear functions of $x.$ All of them can be integrated by parts.

Comment: It's not linear functions of $x$, it's a function of $\cos x$ that involves squares and square root. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%281%2Bx^4%29

Comment: @Sanchez I am a little dazed, so you are right (forgot to backsubstitute). However, (1) square roots are of numbers, not of cosines (2) squares (of cosines) appear under logs, and by factoring the quadratics you get sums of logs of linear functions of cos. All those can be integrated, admittedly in terms of dilogarithms.

Comment: 1. You are right, sorry. 2. I'm not familiar with polylogarithms, but as in comments above 0912 claimed that it has a solution in terms of hypergeometric series, what you said is possibly right then.

Comment: @Sanchez Yes, I am pretty sure (despite being half-asleep and forgetting to back-substitute cosines :))

Answer (score 1):

We can use residue calculus here, although my attempt trades one nasty integral for a slightly simpler one that can be evaluated in terms of hypergeometric functions with a CAS.

---

**Evaluation of $I$**

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{-\tfrac\pi2}^{\tfrac\pi2} \frac{x \sin x}{1+\cos^4x} \, dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{y \sqrt{y^2+1}}{\left(y^2+1\right)^2+1} \arctan y \, dy \tag1 \\
&= i2\pi \sum_{\operatorname{poles}\in\Gamma} \operatorname{Res} \left[\frac{z \sqrt{z^2+1}}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2+1} \arctan z\right] - \underbrace{\int_1^\infty \frac{r \sqrt{r^2-1}}{\left(r^2-1\right)^2+1} \log\frac{r-1}{r+1} \, dr}_J \tag2 \\
&= i2\pi \left(\frac{e^{-\tfrac{i\pi}4}}2 \arctan\sqrt{-1+i} - \frac{e^{\tfrac{i\pi}4}}2 \arctan\sqrt{-1-i}\right) - J \tag3 \\
&= \frac\pi{2\sqrt2} \left(\pi - \arctan\sqrt{2+2\sqrt2} + \log \sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt2-\sqrt{2+2\sqrt2}}{1+\sqrt2+\sqrt{2+2\sqrt2}}}\right) - J
\end{align*}$$

In the output from $(\star)$ linked below, recall $\arctan x+\arctan\dfrac1x=\dfrac\pi2$ if $x>0$, and observe
$$\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac12 = \frac12 \left(-1+\sqrt2\right) = \frac1{2\left(1+\sqrt2\right)}$$

to simplify the non-hypergeometric term in our result to

$$I = \frac\pi{\sqrt2} \ln\left(2 \sqrt[4]{\frac{1+\sqrt2-\sqrt{2+2\sqrt2}}{1+\sqrt2+\sqrt{2+2\sqrt2}}}\right) + 2 \, {}_4F_3 \left(\left.\begin{array}{c}\frac14,\frac12,1,1 \\ \frac34,\frac54,\frac54\end{array}\right\rvert {-1}\right) + \frac{3\pi}{32\sqrt2} \, {}_4F_3 \left(\left.\begin{array}{c}1,1,\frac54,\frac74 \\ \frac32,2,2\end{array}\right\rvert {-1}\right)$$

We happen to have the [identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400316/closed-form-of-the-hypergeometric-function-4f-3-left-beginarrayc1-1-tfra),

$$\begin{align*}
{}_4F_3 \left(\left.\begin{array}{c}1,1,\frac54,\frac74 \\ \frac32,2,2\end{array}\right\rvert {-t}\right) &= \frac{16}{3t}\ln\left(\frac14\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+t}}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+t}}+\sqrt{2}\right)\right) \\[1ex]
\implies {}_4F_3 \left(\left.\begin{array}{c}1,1,\frac54,\frac74 \\ \frac32,2,2\end{array}\right\rvert {-1}\right) &= \frac{32}3 \ln\left(\frac12 \sqrt[4]{\frac{1+\sqrt2+\sqrt{2+2\sqrt2}}{1+\sqrt2-\sqrt{2+2\sqrt2}}}\right)
\end{align*}$$

so we reduce the result further to a single hypergeometric expression,

$$I = \boxed{2 \, {}_4F_3 \left(\left.\begin{array}{c}\frac14,\frac12,1,1 \\ \frac34,\frac54,\frac54\end{array}\right\rvert {-1}\right)}$$

---

**Massaging $J$**

Substituting $t^2=\dfrac{r-1}{r+1}$ then $2u=\dfrac1t-t$ yields a "simpler" integral,

$$\begin{align*}
J &= \int_1^\infty \frac{r \sqrt{r^2-1}}{\left(r^2-1\right)^2+1} \log\frac{r-1}{r+1} \, dr \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{16t^2(t^2+1)}{t^8-4t^6+22t^4-4t^2+1}\log t\,dt \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{16\left(1+\frac1{t^2}\right)}{t^4+\frac1{t^4} - 4\left(t^2+\frac1{t^2}\right) + 22} \log t \, dt \\
&= 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\log\left(\sqrt{u^2+1}-u\right)}{u^4+1} \, du \\
&= -2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\operatorname{arsinh} u}{u^4+1} \, du
\end{align*}$$

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+arcsinh%28u%29%2F%28u%5E4%2B1%29+from+0+to+inf) $(\star)$ can evaluate $J$ and even finds an antiderivative.

---

**Explanation**

- $(1)$ : substitute $y=\tan x$
- $(2)$ : residue theorem; see below for more details
- $(3)$ : compute the residues at $-\sqrt{-1-i}=\sqrt[4]{2}\,e^{i\tfrac{5\pi}8}$ and $\sqrt{-1+i}=\sqrt[4]{2}\,e^{i\tfrac{3\pi}8}$ (using the convention $\sqrt z=\sqrt{\left|z\right|}\,e^{\tfrac i2\arg z}$ and $-\pi<\arg z\le \pi$); to simplify, we have

$$\begin{align*}
\arctan\sqrt{-1+i} &= \frac i2 \log \frac{1-i\sqrt{-1+i}}{1+i\sqrt{-1+i}} \\
&= \frac i2 \log\left(-2i - 1 - 2\sqrt{-1+i}\right) \\
&= \frac{\pi - \arctan \sqrt{2+2\sqrt2}}2 + i \log\sqrt{1+\sqrt2+\sqrt{2+2\sqrt2}} \\[2ex]
\arctan\sqrt{-1\color{red}{-}i} &= \frac{\pi - \arctan \sqrt{2+2\sqrt2}}2 + i \log\sqrt{1+\sqrt2\color{red}{-}\sqrt{2+2\sqrt2}}
\end{align*}$$

---

**Applying the residue theorem**

Let $f(z)$ be the integrand, swapping $y$ for the complex variable $z$, and let $\Gamma$ denote an indented, semicircular contour. We make a cut along the imaginary axis at $[i,i\infty)$ (as well as along $[-i,-i\infty)$, but that's not totally relevant here). $\Gamma$ is composed of a line segment of length $2R$; a large, broken semicircle centered at the origin of radius $R$; a smaller, broken circle centered at $+i$ of radius $\varepsilon$; and two opposing line segments joining the arcs. Here's a rough sketch:

[image]

I claim without proof that the integrals along the circular contours vanish as $R\to\infty$ and as $\varepsilon\to0$.

On our selected branch we have

$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{z^2+1} &= \sqrt{\left|z^2+1\right|} e^{\tfrac i2 \arg(z^2+1)} \\[1ex]
\arctan z &= \frac i2 \log \frac{1-iz}{1+iz} \\
&= \frac i2 \left(\log\left|\frac{1-iz}{1+iz}\right| + i \arg\frac{1-iz}{1+iz}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Both $\sqrt{z^2+1}$ and $\arctan z$ behave similarly to either side of the cut in the sense that the argument term for both component functions approaches $-\pi$ from the left/outward bank and $+\pi$ from the right/inward bank. In summary,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rm bank & \rm path & f(z) \\
\hline
\rm outward & \begin{cases}z = ir e^{i\phi} \\ dz = i e^{i\phi} \, dr \\ r\in[1+\varepsilon,R]\end{cases} & \displaystyle \frac{z\,e^{-\tfrac{i\pi}2}\,\sqrt{\left|z^2+1\right|}}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2+1} \cdot \frac i2 \left(\log\left|\frac{1-iz}{1+iz}\right| - \frac{i\pi}2\right) \\
\hline
\rm inward & \begin{cases}z = ir e^{-i\phi} \\ dz = ie^{-i\phi} \, dr \\ r\in[R,1+\varepsilon]\end{cases} & \displaystyle \frac{z \, e^{\tfrac{i\pi}2} \, \sqrt{\left|z^2+1\right|}}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2+1} \cdot \frac i2 \left(\log\left|\frac{1-iz}{1+iz}\right| + \frac{i\pi}2\right) \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

As $\phi\to0$, the integrals along the banks converge to, and provide a total contribution of,

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{\rm out} f(z) \, dz &= -\frac12 \int_1^\infty \frac{r \sqrt{r^2-1}}{\left(r^2-1\right)^2+1} \left(\log\frac{r+1}{r-1} - i\pi\right) \, dr \\[2ex]
\int_{\rm in} f(z) \, dz &= -\frac12 \int_1^\infty \frac{r \sqrt{r^2-1}}{\left(r^2-1\right)^2+1} \left(\log\frac{r+1}{r-1} + i\pi\right) \, dr  \\[2ex]
\implies \int_{\rm net} f(z) \, dz &= \int_1^\infty \frac{r \sqrt{r^2-1}}{\left(r^2-1\right)^2+1} \log\frac{r-1}{r+1} \, dr \\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Could you find 1.845...?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this integral has a closed solution. I used both [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com) and [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org) to calculate the indefinite integral, $\int\frac{\sin{x}}{1+\cos^{4}{x}}$ but both failed. However you can use a [numerical method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) to get an approximate answer to a precision of your liking. Sage gives the approximate answer 1.8450963514045045.

Comment: Mathematica gives answer as a generalized hypergeometric function: 2HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4, 1/2, 1, 1}, {3/4, 5/4, 5/4}, -1].

Comment: @0912, http://goo.gl/LrP9Wh

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee, Yes? Looks like Wolframalpha can't compute it. It exceeds the computation time.

Answer (score 0):

$$2\;_4F_3[1/4,1/2,1,1;3/4,5/4,5/4;-1]=2\times0.922548...$$. B the substitution $u=\cos x$, expanding the denominator and integrating termwise. I don't think it can be reduced to an elementary expression.