# Closed form for ${_3F_2}\!\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac34,1,1\\\tfrac32,\tfrac74\end{array}\middle|1\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, closed-form

I am trying to find the closed form the expression $${_3F_2}\!\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac34,1,1\\\tfrac32,\tfrac74\end{array}\middle|1\right).$$ I was able to convert the expression into the series $${_3F_2}\!\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac34,1,1\\\tfrac32,\tfrac74\end{array}\middle|1\right)=\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{3 \cdot 4^n}{(4n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}$$ using the [series definition of the generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) and properties of the Pochhammer symbol/gamma function. Since $\frac{1}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}} = \mathrm{B}(n+1,n+1)$ where $\mathrm{B}$ is the beta function, I tried substituting the integral representation of the beta function into the sum and interchanging the order of summation and integration to get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{3 \cdot 4^n}{(4n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}
&= \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{3 \cdot 4^n}{(4n+3)}\mathrm{B}(n+1,n+1)\\
&= \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{3 \cdot 4^n}{4n+3} \int_0^1 t^n (1-t)^n\,dt\\
&= \int_0^1\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{3 \cdot 4^n}{4n+3} t^n (1-t)^n\,dt.
\end{align*}
According the Mathematica, the series can be simplified down to
$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{3 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{1-t} \sqrt[4]{t}\right)}{4 \sqrt{2} (1-t)^{3/4} t^{3/4}}-\frac{3 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{1-t} \sqrt[4]{t}\right)}{4 \sqrt{2} (1-t)^{3/4} t^{3/4}}\right)\,dt.$$ From here, I do not know how to proceed. Is there a better way of approaching this or is this perhaps already a known hypergeometric function identity, like the one found in [this previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400316/closed-form-of-the-hypergeometric-function-4f-3-left-beginarrayc1-1-tfra)?